# VS Code: How to hide the bottom panel, no matter which tab I'm on?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've found shortcuts to show/hide Problems (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) or Output (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), but these require two button presses to hide the bottom pane if it's *not* currently on those respective tabs.

How can I hide and show the bottom panel with a single button press, regardless of which tab is currently active?  Similar functionality as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, which hides the left-hand bar no matter whether Explorer, Debug etc. is active.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

By default in VSCode <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> shows and hides the Panel, no matter which one you are focused on.

[image: KeyboardShortcuts.json]

Comment: Yes it does -- It does not STAY closed.

Comment: This works great for me. Just a heads up, it will not work if you have other commands that use the same keybinding. In my case command+j would join lines. Removing that keybinding makes this work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to hide the panel by default, at startup?

Answer (score 8):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you're only interested in *hiding* the bottom panel then you can just hit either of these shortcuts twice: (*i.e.*
 <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) once to take you to that panel, the second to hide that panel.

Comment: The OP addresses this solution in the post, however it is a valid answer. Just think of that in the future.

Comment: This doesn't work consistently, because if the Problems panel is already showing, then double-tapping M will *show* the Problems panel, not hide it.  So there's a slowdown every time I just want to "hide the bottom bar" - I have to tap the shortcut, pay attention to whether it's dismissed, and possibly tap it again.  I'm looking for a solution where I can *reliably* dismiss it with a single key and not break focus at all.  I may have to do it in Keyboard Maestro (check for an image on the screen to see if bottom bar is open, click the Close button).

Comment: This method does work *usually*, but it is curiously roundabout.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

This shortcut is responsible for showing/hiding the bottom panel that contains terminal, debug, output, etc.

Comment: Actually no, this only hides the panel if the terminal is focused.  Otherwise, if any of the other panel tabs is focused - like Problems or Output - it changes focus to the Terminal tab but does not hide the panel.

Comment: Yes, doing the shortcut twice will hide it, firstly it will focus Terminal, secondly it will hide the panel.

Comment: The question does ask for  "a single button press..." though.

Answer (score 1):

For a single button solution to close the panel no matter what is currently selected, you can make a custom hotkey to run the `workbench.action.closePanel` action.

In `keybindings.json` add something like this:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+j",
  "command": "workbench.action.closePanel"
},
```

The above will override `cmd+j` to always close the panel instead of toggle it. For more info, check out the [docs for finding and working with keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization).

I don't see `workbench.action.closePanel` in [online command references docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) right now, but it does work for me on VS Code version `1.84.2`. It also comes up in the autocomplete options when working in `keybindings.json`, which seems to be the real source of truth about what's available.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) keyboard shortcut to show or hide the panel window (containing terminal, debug console etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To assign your custom keyboard shortcut to do this, add something like this to your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "alt+v",
    "command": "workbench.action.togglePanel"
},
```

If you're interested in removing the default shortcut for it:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+j",
    "command": "-workbench.action.togglePanel"
},
```

Finally found this after wondering about this for months :P